# Journal Article Same year - Avoid a, b in the year after ex: 2016a

Tags: formatting

I am preparing my resume in the overleaf.com and I have 3 papers in the same year. In output, I am getting a , b , c after the year like 2016a, 2016b, 2016c. But I don't want a,b , c after the year.

Code:

```
@article{lim:etal:kdtei:ICEEE2016,
title = {Effect XXX},
author = {\textbf{ABC} },
year = {2016},
volume = {9 (35)},
pages = {1-5},
journal = {Journal of Science and Technology},
% issn = {2167-9843},
}

@article{lim:etal:kdtei:LREV2016,
title = {Effect Of },
author = {\textbf{ABC} },
year = {2016},
volume = {4},
pages = {10863-10869},
journal = {Materials Today: Proceedings, Publisher Elesvier},
% issn = {2167-9843},
}
```

OUTPUT

```
ABC. (2016a). Effect XXX.Journal of Science and Technology,9 (35), 1–5.
ABC. (2016b). Effect of .Materials Today: Proceedings, Publisher Elesvier,4, 10863–10869.
```

I want to avoid `a` and `b` after the year 2016 in the output file.

Please help me out.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us how you create the formatted bib entries at present. Do you use a software too? If so, which one?

Comment: I am using just overleaf.com

Comment: the formatting is specified by your bibtex style about which you have given no information.

Comment: Sorry, but `overleaf` is a website, *not* a TeX distribution. (If you insist, you might call overleaf a "front end" to a TeX distribution.) Do please reveal whether you use BibTeX, biblatex, or some other tool to create the formatted bibliographic entries.

Comment: if you don't have b and c how will the reader know which reference is meant by `\cite{lim:etal:kdtei:LREV2016} `  if it makes the same citation text as `\cite{lim:etal:kdtei:ICEEE2016}` ??

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to latex . Just modifying the existing resume to mine